# Meteor publish not working for private service.facebook.email publication

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is a Meteor/MongoDb question. In the code below, I am attempting to give all clients access to all users' Facebook names and Facebook profile Ids.

At the same time, I am attempting to give clients access to *their own* email as defined on their Facebook profiles.

```
Meteor.publish("users", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:
    {'services.facebook.name': true,
    'services.facebook.id': true}
    })
});

Meteor.publish("mail", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
        {fields: {'services.facebook.email': 1}});
});
```

In the code below is how I have subscribed to the above publications.

```
Meteor.subscribe("users");
Meteor.subscribe("mail");
```

This should work as far as I am aware, yet when I attempt to make use of the user object, such as in the code below...

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
console.log(user);
```

... I receive only the parts of the user object published as standard (profile.name & _id) and the parts of the user object published by the first meteor.publish function in the code above ("users"). The user's Facebook email is nowhere to be found. The code below demonstrates what I consistently keep receiving when I run the above findOne code.

```
{
_id: "3aNP7euRFGWhGEgq2",
profile: {name: "David Daish"},
services: {facebook: {name: "David Daish", ID: "1987779184781528"}}
}
```

As you can see, the Facebook email property is nowhere to be found. It's zilch, gone, not there. So there is my question:

**How can I get services.facebook.email's value, and more importantly, how can I do it in a way that allows clients access to only their own services.facebook.email value?**

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance. This has been confounding me for a couple days.